# DNS reverting in Windows Server 2003

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, dhcp, ipconfig

I have a Windows Server 2003. It is connected to a number of networked databases but stopped working this morning. It was receiving DNS from an old DC which we have just retired. I tried to change the settings manually. Afterwards it asked to be restarted. After I restarted it booted back up with the old DNS settings again. Nightmare. I have also discovered an old XP box with the same issue. I am not sure what is doing this. It is picking up DHCP from the correct server which is also one of 2 DNS servers. The DHCP server is set with the right DNS server addresses. However I cant point this one server at it or leave it blank as it changes the DNS back. Please help.

Comment: Why would it ask to restart on a dns update?  set it again it should not ask to be rebooted.

Comment: do you get a clean reboot, if the reboot crashes as in you get the message that "the previous reboot was unexpected" then any settings you've made won't stick.

Answer (score 1):

Check Resultant Set of Policy. Somebody may have used the evil, nasty mechanism in Group Policy that can be used to specify DNS server addresses.

Comment: yuck but almost sounds plausible in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Manually set the IP and DNS settings for it. Don't allow an auto assigned DHCP address but use an address from the DHCP pool.

Comment: i think he said he tried that "I tried to change the settings manually"

Comment: I thought he meant only for the DNS settings.  I was recommending he manually set the IP address as well.